How to merge swagger documentation using FastAPI?
I have two FastAPI services running on different ports:
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/test/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}


version: '3.9'
services:

  first:
    build:
      context: ./first
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  second:
    build:
      context: ./second
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"


I need one endpoint where I can select services with the documentation I need, something like this:

How can I combine the swagger documentation for these services? The documentation for FastAPI says that you can make a custom one, but I don’t know how to combine them into one endpoint.

I cloned the official repository https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui. I created a separate service, moved the /dist folder to it and changed the paths in the swagger-initializer.js file:
window.onload = function() {
 //<editor-fold desc="Changeable Configuration Block">

 // the following lines will be replaced by docker/configurator, when it 
runs in a docker-container
 window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    urls: [
      {url: "http://localhost:8000/openapi.json", name: "First Service"},
      {url: "http://localhost:9000/openapi.json", name: "Second Service"},
    ],
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
 });
 //</editor-fold>
};

Added Dockerfile
FROM node:14
RUN npm install -g http-server
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["http-server", "/usr/share/nginx/html", "-p", "80"]

And I got this interface:


You might find this answer and this answer helpful as well.
